# Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5 version . When I try to start the server it throws the below error.
When I list the gem its shows the rake there but of different version

```
actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
bundler (1.1.3)
fattr (2.2.1)
git (1.2.5)
postgres-pr (0.6.3)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rush (0.6.8)
session (3.1.0)
```

Please help me to figure out this issue .

```
D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `materialize': Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:172:in `specs_for'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `setup'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
        from D:/safecellweb/config/boot.rb:116:in `load_gems'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from D:/safecellweb/config/environment.rb:10
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from script/server:4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your rake version is 0.9.2

While your app required 0.8.7

so first uninstall rake 0.9.2 by this command

```
gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2
```

then install rake 0.8.7 by this command

```
gem install rake -v=0.8.7
```

Hope your issue will be solve........

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands the problem will fix
step 1:install rake **gem install rake -v '0.8.7'**

step 2: install bundler **gem install bundler**

step 3: **bundle install**

it will fix the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem while running an application using RubyMine.

Steps taken by me:
1) I installed new Ruby on my machine.
2) Changed the path of Ruby in environment variables.
3) Changed the path of Ruby in RubyMine using following steps:-
   a) Click **File** -> **Settings** -> **Ruby SDK and Gems**
4) Then ran *bundle install*